# Сдвинуть горы или свернуть горы?

Tags: фразеология

Почему нам нужно горы не двигать, не сдвинуть, а непременно свернуть?

Обычно с помощью этого "мирного" и многозначного глагола можно свернуть в трубочку бумажный лист или свернуть на другую улицу. Правда, есть еще  "ударом, толчком сдвинуть, сбить на сторону; своротить".

Но откуда такая экспрессия, ведь речь идет не о разрушении, а о созидательной вере в свои силы?

Comment: Интересно, что из глубин моей памяти не поднимается ни один случай со словом "горы" ***после*** глагола.  Всё, что припоминатеся, сначала имеет "горы", а потом - глагол.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А ещё: свернуть шею или челюсть, а ещё свернуть дела, или разговор, или даже отношения.  Экспрессия при этом присутствует или нет, но созидание отсутствует точно.)

Бывает часто свёрнуто производство, строительство и т.п. Тоже отсутствие созидания, только масштабы  другие, - как правило, больше горы.

В данном случае глагол "свернуть" предполагает, что  у того, кто намерен им воспользоваться на практике, должно быть много сил.
Гора ведь всегда являлась мерилом непреодолимого препятствия - "умный в гору не пойдёт, умный гору обойдёт". Ну,а кто-то попрёт! ))

Образность русского языка закрепилась в идущем из старины словосочетании.

Comment: Свернуть отношения или свернуть строительство - это привести их обратно к нулевой точке. Здесь семантика двух действий: развернуть - свернуть, ничего разрушительного. А  агрессивное сбить/сдвинуть основано на значении "повернуть вокруг своей оси так, что конструкция будет разрушена".  Образность, конечно, свойственна устойчивым сочетаниям, но здесь именно разрушительная образность: не только сдвинем, но и сломаем заодно.

Answer (score 2):

Гору нельзя сдвинуть: слишком глубоко в землю закопана. Зато свернуть ("ей шею") или своротить её с "фундамента" проще, чем вытащить из земли. На её месте иногда удобно что-нибудь построить, именно так строится у Жёлтого моря Тяньваньская АЭС.

Comment: Подходит библейский человек к горному массиву - и горы перед ним расступаются, так велика его вера. Подходит русский человек к горе и думает: "Нет, такое не сдвинешь, легче сломать".